# laravel authorization - allow user to edit own profile

Tags: laravel, authorization, laravel-5.1

I have 3 user types: admin, teacher, student.

I created a policy `manage` so that only admins can edit users:

**UserController**:

```
$this->authorize('manage', User::class);
```

**UserPolicy**:

```
public function manage($user) {
    return $user->type === 'admin';
}
```

where `$user` is the currently authenticated user.

I would like to modify my `manage` policy so that a User can modify his own profile. I have tried:

**UserController**:

```
$this->authorize('manage', User::class, $userToEdit);
```

**UserPolicy**:

```
public function manage($user, $userToEdit) {
    return $user->type === 'admin' || $user->id === $userToEdit->id;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: what problem you are getting to use that?

Comment: @ImtiazPabel I am getting Unauthorized error

Comment: first dump your $userToEdit,and check is their exist any data.And also check data type cause you are using (===)